Record video with browser/web overlay - make overlay embedded in the saved video
I am wondering is it possible to place a web overlay on top of the camera video and save both the video and overlay in the video file?
I was looking for any camera app on ios and android which can save both camera video and web overlay in file, but it seems it does not exist.
So I would like to build one with react native.  So is it possible?
PS another feature I would like to ask is, is it possible to add instance replay?  E.g. on the app I developed, I press a button the screen and saved video will replay the last 10 seconds of the captured video?  Is it possible in react native?
Thanks
